# Using shapefile as an input to the user defined function using R

Tags: r, function, shapefile

I have a script to create a randomly distributed square polygons in KML format which takes in shapefile with a single polygon as an input which works absolutely well. The problem arise when I tried to create the user defined function out of it. I used readShapePoly() function to read the shapefile and it works well when used out of the function. But when the function is created in which shapefile should be given as an input, it simply wont take. It shows this error message
**Error in getinfo.shape(filen) : Error opening SHP file**
I avoid writing extensions and I do have all the extension files to create the shapefile.
Part of the script to read the shapefile using it as the input file:

```
library(maptools)   
library(sp)             
library(ggplot2)        

Polytokml  <-  function(shapefile_name){

###Input Files
file1 <- "shapefile_name"


Shape_file  <-  readShapePoly(file1)  #requires maptools
return(Shape_file)
}
```

The function is created but it doesn't work if the function is called.

```
>Polytokml(HKH.shp)
Error in getinfo.shape(filen) : Error opening SHP file
```

This works well out of the function.

```
###Input Files
file1 <- "shapefile.shp"
Shape_file  <-  readShapePoly(file1)  #requires maptools
```

This is just an example out of the whole script in which different arguments are taken as an input. So just to make things simple I have added script to read the shapefile which has been a problem now. Do let me know if it is not clear.

Thank you so much in advance :)

Comment: If it's the whole script you posted, your function is trying to open a file called "shapefile_name".

Comment: @Pascal : Hey thank you very much.No it's not the whole script. It's just the par to the script which tries to read the shapefile and it works well when no function is created but gives error messages as I tried to read the shapefile by calling the function